# disable responsive on desktop view port sizes only

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to disable my bootstrap 3.0 theme for md, sm responsiveness, I just want it to look different when it is viewed by a cellphone.

The answers I read in the linked question are for disabling the responsiveness completely for everything, I just want to disable responsiveness for tablets, I want to keep the responsiveness for cellphones.

Is there a way to do this?
I do not know less, can I do it from the css file directly?
My website is already built, works fine in desktop but when I resize the browser window, lots of things get out of place, it works well on the cellphone.

Comment: If you don't care about particular screen sizes, then just don't use the classes with those sizes in their names. Sounds like you only care about XS and SM. (Remember that SM styles also apply to MD and LG screens by default, unless overridden by other classes for those larger sizes.) I encourage you to re-read Bootstrap's grid system docs.

Comment: I voted to re-open. Edit your question to state disable responsive on desktop view port sizes only.

Answer (score 1):

Please see here: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/

Steps to disable page responsiveness

1. Omit the viewport  mentioned in the CSS docs
2. Override the width  on the .container for each grid tier with a
   single width, for example    width: 970px !important; Be sure that this comes after
   the default    Bootstrap CSS. You can optionally avoid the
   !important with media    queries or some selector-fu.
3. If using navbars, remove all navbar collapsing and expanding
   behavior.
4. For grid layouts, use .col-xs-* classes in addition to, or in place
   of, the medium/large ones. Don't worry, the extra-small device
   grid scales to all resolutions.

   You'll still need Respond.js for IE8 (since our media queries are
   still there and need to be processed). This disables the "mobile
   site" aspects of Bootstrap.

Comment: Hi! thank you for your answer sylwester, I just want to leave the responsiveness for the cellphone, I do not want to cancel the responsiveness for the cellphone, I understand that if I do the steps you sent, I will dissable the responsiveness for everything? thanks